# Euclid numbers are always of the form $4m+3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

The Euclid numbers are defined as $P_n:=p_1p_2...p_n+1$ where the $p_i$ are the prime numbers. I need show that $P_n$ is always of the form $4m+3$ for $m \in \mathbb{N}_0$.

I have found proofs for showing that there are infinitely many primes of the form $4m+3$ based on Euclid's proof of infinitely many primes. However how can I use this result to show that every Euclid number is of this form?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Can the product of distinct primes be divisible by $4$?  Can this product in particular be odd?

Comment: From the duplicate:"squares are $\equiv 0, 1 \pmod 4$. Since $p_1 p_2 \cdots p_n$ has only one factor of $2$, it is $\equiv \pm2 \pmod 4$, so $p_1 p_2 \cdots p_n + 1 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$"

Comment: Also solved many times at [art of problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c5h1495253p8794940).

Answer (score 3):

$p_1=2$.

Then for all $i\ge2$, $p_i$ is odd so $p_i\equiv-1\pmod4$ or $p_i\equiv1\pmod4$. If you multiply all of them you get either $p_2\cdots p_n\equiv-1\pmod4$ or $p_2\cdots p_n\equiv1\pmod4$. In both cases you get $p_1\cdots p_n\equiv2\pmod4$ (which is the same as $p_1\cdots p_n\equiv-2\pmod4$).

Therefore there exists an integer $m$ such that $p_1\cdots p_n=4m+2$, hence $P_n=4m+3$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).